# Temporarily disabling Bluebird warnings in tests

Tags: promise, bluebird

When implementing tests that knowingly produce warnings from Bluebird....

Is there a way to disable all warnings for a specific test or even a test line?

I mean, is there any provision for it in the library?

I know about the [global configuration](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.config.html) and how to switch warnings off completely, but this is not what I'm looking for.

**clarification**

This is for negative tests that are supposed to be invalid. I just don't want Bluebird to pollute the console with warnings for such specific tests. I'm looking for a way to say in any given test - `Warnings in this test are by design, do not write anything into the console`.

Comment: Yes. Fix the cause of the warning. They aren't unsubstantiated.

Comment: @Bergi This is for negative tests that are supposed to be invalid. I just don't want Bluebird to pollute the console with warnings for such specific tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `NODE_ENV` environment variable. 
Use either `production` or `test` for different verbosity levels.

Comment: It'll switch off all the warnings, which isn't what I want, and it is too dangerous in a large test suit.